# Doesn't .NET support .NET Framework apps?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, .net-framework, .net-core

.NET (formerly known as .NET Core) replaced .NET Framework years ago.

One can argue Windows 10 was unfortunately released before this transition, but why does [Windows 11 have .NET Framework built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-11)?

Does it mean .NET apps can only be run by .NET while .NET Framework apps can only be run by .NET Framework? If so, does it also apply to versions (e.g. .NET 6.0 apps can't be run by NET 7.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean .NET apps can only be run by .NET while .NET Framework apps can only be run by .NET Framework?

That is exactly what it means. **.NET Core** applications cannot be run without the appropriate version of **.NET Core** being installed in the system.

> If so, does it also apply to versions (e.g. .NET 6.0 apps can't be run by NET 7.0)?

It depends. If a developer were to target .NET Core 7 specifically, then you would need that version installed to run the application. Likewise, if you had .NET Core 7 installed and ran an application that targeted an earlier version of .NET Core, then it would work.

> One can argue Windows 10 was unfortunately released before this transition, but why does Windows 11 have .NET Framework built-in?

Windows 11 has .NET Framework 4.8.X built-in for the purpose of backward compatibility. .NET Framework 4.8.X will be supported as long as Windows 10 is supported, and honestly, probably for the considerable future (i.e., until Windows 11 support ends).

Applications targeted towards .NET Framework 4.8 still require it. .NET Core and .NET Framework are not in-place replacements for each other. .NET Core is the open-source version of .NET Framework.

Until the open source version can support everything that .NET Framework can support, .NET Framework 4.8 (and .NET 3.5) must exist, and given the number of legacy applications that require it, .NET Framework 4.8 isn’t going anywhere.